# Different result from a bash function

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I am trying to code a script to log all commands executed on a server, currently I have 2 versions:

(simplified version of the scripts)

Version 1:

```
function fc
{
  fc -ln -0
}
trap fc DEBUG
```

Version 2:

```
function fc
{
 cmd=`fc -ln -0`
 echo $cmd
}
trap fc DEBUG
```

The script is inluded in /etc/bash.bashrc : `source script.sh`

The problem is that when I run this scripts I don't get the same result:

When I run the first verion I get the command that triggered the trap :

```
SERVER#
SERVER#
SERVER# test
SERVER# ls
ls
```

But when I run the second I get the last-1 command :

```
SERVER#
SERVER#
SERVER# test
SERVER# ls
test
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the 2nd version, you're executing `fc` in a different process, so you won't have the same history.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, I have tried to run this directly in bash cmd=`fc -ln -0; echo $cmd and cmd=`fc -ln -0`, I had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a function for `trap DEBUG` then you can make use of special BASH variable `BASH_COMMAND`.

```
dbg() { echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> ~/cmd.log }

trap 'dbg' DEBUG
```

**Make sure this `trap` command is very last line in your `~/.bashrc` (or last line in ~/.bash_profile, if that exists).**

Comment: is it going to impact general system performance if I put trap debug in /etc/bashrc?

Comment: Not really, I have even used `trap debug` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` together.

Comment: Ok. When I connect to the server I see some commands from others scripts (~/.bashrc, ..) it there a way to ignore those scripts. thanks

Comment: So do you just want to store each and every executed command in a file?